# Sorting items but preventing same named items being next to eachother; also adding randomization in sets

Tags: python, list, algorithm, orders

I'm trying to figure out what sorting algorithms I would need to use to create a "recent" list but preventing the items with the same names from appearing next to each other but also with the ability to randomize in sets....

For example, if we have the following raw data:

```
Apple   10/02/2020
Apple   15/02/2020
Apple   10/03/2020
Apple   15/03/2020
Apple   10/04/2020
Apple   15/04/2020
Banana  16/03/2020
Banana  21/03/2020
Banana  16/04/2020
Orange  13/03/2020
Orange  15/03/2020
```

I want to sort it so it would roughly look like the data shown below (most recent item first from each item name). Of course we run out of Oranges and Bananas so the last 4 items all have to be Apples but that can't be helped.

```
Banana  16/04/2020
Apple   15/04/2020
Orange  15/03/2020
Banana  21/03/2020
Apple   10/04/2020
Orange  13/03/2020
Banana  16/03/2020
Apple   15/03/2020
Apple   10/03/2020
Apple   15/02/2020
Apple   10/02/2020
```

## Issue: Repetitive "groups"

The only issue with this sorting order is that we have a repetitive groups of `Banana`, `Apple`, `Orange` over and over. So we want to optionally sort a groups into a somewhat randomized order. The "groups" size would be defined by a number we choose; not by the number of items.

So if we set the "group" to 3 it would look at the above order and randomize each set of 3, thus looking like:

```
Orange  15/03/2020
Apple   15/04/2020
Banana  16/04/2020
---
Banana  21/03/2020
Orange  13/03/2020
Apple   10/04/2020
---
Banana  16/03/2020
Apple   15/03/2020
Apple   10/03/2020
---
Apple   10/02/2020
Apple   15/02/2020
```

## Issue: Lost the "most recent".

The problem with the sorted group **above** is that the most recent item has been randomly put to the bottom of the first set; of course this won't always be the case but in this example it has been.

Maybe there is a way to keep the first group's order and either randomize the following groups OR just re-order so that the groups order is NOT the same as the previous groups order; for example:

```
Banana  16/04/2020
Apple   15/04/2020
Orange  15/03/2020
---
Apple   10/04/2020
Orange  13/03/2020
Banana  21/03/2020
---
Banana  16/03/2020
Apple   15/03/2020
Apple   10/03/2020
---
Apple   15/02/2020
Apple   10/02/2020
```

**OR**

```
Banana  16/04/2020
Apple   15/04/2020
Orange  15/03/2020
---
Banana  21/03/2020
Orange  13/03/2020
Apple   10/04/2020
---
Apple   15/03/2020
Banana  16/03/2020
Apple   10/03/2020
---
Apple   10/02/2020
Apple   15/02/2020
```

Comment: Why are you not considering orders like apple banana apple orange apple banana... ?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean? If you want a randomized order of course they won't be ordered by most recent anymore.  If all you care about is having items separated into unique groups, then just sort it by group and then sort the first group by most recent? Maybe an example of what you've tried would benefit you here.

Comment: @billy because I want to get the most recent for as many unique items as possible, otherwise on some lists it would just switch between two items for too long before showing the other items.

Comment: @r.ook I've covered that in my post when mentioning groups, by ordering the items and then splitting it into groups (in my example I chose group sizes of 3) and only applying the randomisation to groups to make each shown group look more unique

Comment: What is your original data type? Plain text? `DataFrame`? Some other...?

Comment: @r.ook We pull the data from postgresql but we haven't decided how we are going to store prepare it. So we could use pandas if need be; however I'm not exactly looking for code examples to help me get it started rather the logic. I've been going through sorting algorithms like you can see https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/sorting-algorithms/ to try and figure out what ones I should be using.

Comment: I think it would be more productive to have a concrete example or decisions made, as the answer could vary based on the final structure.  e.g. The approach between plain text or `pandas` would be very different.  IMO this is a premature discussion, but I digress.  If I understood you correctly, it's a matter of ranking the recency in group of items, spit out a "group" size of 3 for each rank 1, 2, 3, etc... as long as you are okay with `Banana, Orange, Apple` occurring in the same pattern when the recency ranking is the same between groups.

Comment: Yeah, I can get to the result of repeating the pattern of `Banana, Orange, Apple` whilst preserving their recency fairly easily but I'm trying to find the logic to prevent having that repeating pattern.

Comment: Then it's just a matter of what you want to do with the repeats, which can be handled as well, You might check the next group if the pattern is the same, if so, apply a function e.g. `random.shuffle` to mix the order and return.  But again would be a much more fruitful conversation if it was more concrete.

Answer (score 1):

I decided to think of it as sorting the individual fruits by date then interleaving them.
If I set up each freuitdate to depend on the next fruitdate in time, but only have time dependencies btween the same fruits; then [topological sort](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Topological_sort) can be used to split items into sub-groups of differing fruits as above. I could then order the first such group by time, then the other subgroups randomly.

The code:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Created on Wed Apr 29 09:21:15 2020

Answer to:
    https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61485884/sorting-items-but-preventing-same-named-items-being-next-to-eachother-also-addi

@author: Paddy3118
"""

from random import shuffle
from functools import reduce


def toposort2(data):
    "Based on: http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Topological_sort#Python"

    for k, v in data.items():
        v.discard(k) # Ignore self dependencies
    extra_items_in_deps = reduce(set.union, data.values()) - set(data.keys())
    data.update({item:set() for item in extra_items_in_deps})
    while True:
        ordered = set(item for item,dep in data.items() if not dep)
        if not ordered:
            break
        #yield ' '.join(sorted(ordered))  ## The one change!!
        yield sorted(ordered)
        data = {item: (dep - ordered) for item,dep in data.items()
                if item not in ordered}
    assert not data, "A cyclic dependency exists amongst %r" % data

#%%

raw = """
Apple   10/02/2020
Apple   15/02/2020
Apple   10/03/2020
Apple   15/03/2020
Apple   10/04/2020
Apple   15/04/2020
Banana  16/03/2020
Banana  21/03/2020
Banana  16/04/2020
Orange  13/03/2020
Orange  15/03/2020
"""


def fruit_yearmonthday(fruitdate):
    "Order fields, (esp. dates), for item sorting"
    fruit, date = fruitdate
    d, m, y = date.split('/')
    return fruit, y, m, d


def ymd(fruitdate_string):
    "Order order field dates for partial order sorting"
    fruit, date = fruitdate_string.split()
    d, m, y = date.split('/')
    return y, m, d

#%%
# raw data into individual (frit, date) ruples
items = [tuple(line.split()) for line in raw.strip().split('\n')]
        # [('Apple', '10/02/2020'), ...]

# Order by date of each fruit kind
items.sort(key=fruit_yearmonthday)
    # [('Apple', '10/02/2020'),
    #  ('Apple', '15/02/2020'),
    #  ('Apple', '10/03/2020'),
    #  ('Apple', '15/03/2020'),
    #  ('Apple', '10/04/2020'),
    #  ('Apple', '15/04/2020'),
    #  ('Banana', '16/03/2020'),
    #  ('Banana', '21/03/2020'),
    #  ('Banana', '16/04/2020'),
    #  ('Orange', '13/03/2020'),
    #  ('Orange', '15/03/2020')]
# Stringify
items = [f"{i[0]:6}  {i[1]}" for i in items]

# Initial time-based dependencies only between _same_ fruits
last = items[0]
depends = {}
for fruitdate in items[1:]:
    if last[0] == fruitdate[0]:
        depends[last] = {fruitdate}
    last = fruitdate

partial_order = list(toposort2(depends))
#print("Partial ordering. items on same line could be in any order:\n")
#print ('\n'.join(str(line) for line in partial_order))
    # ['Apple   15/04/2020', 'Banana  16/04/2020', 'Orange  15/03/2020']
    # ['Apple   10/04/2020', 'Banana  21/03/2020', 'Orange  13/03/2020']
    # ['Apple   15/03/2020', 'Banana  16/03/2020']
    # ['Apple   10/03/2020']
    # ['Apple   15/02/2020']
    # ['Apple   10/02/2020']

# An ordering:
# First line by date, then other lines *randomly*
order = []
for linenum, line in enumerate(partial_order):
    if linenum == 0:
        order += sorted(line, key=ymd, reverse=True)
    else:
        shuffle(line)
        order += line

print("\nAN ORDERING OF ITEMS:")
for item in order:
    print(f'  {item}')
```

Sevral runs show that the first three items and the last three are always the same, but the fourth-to-sixth are randomised, as are the seventh-to-eigth.

**Sample runs:**

```
AN ORDERING OF ITEMS:
  Banana  16/04/2020
  Apple   15/04/2020
  Orange  15/03/2020
  Apple   10/04/2020
  Banana  21/03/2020
  Orange  13/03/2020
  Apple   15/03/2020
  Banana  16/03/2020
  Apple   10/03/2020
  Apple   15/02/2020
  Apple   10/02/2020

runcell(2, 'C:/Users/Paddy3118/Google Drive/Code/fruit_orderings.py')

AN ORDERING OF ITEMS:
  Banana  16/04/2020
  Apple   15/04/2020
  Orange  15/03/2020
  Orange  13/03/2020
  Banana  21/03/2020
  Apple   10/04/2020
  Apple   15/03/2020
  Banana  16/03/2020
  Apple   10/03/2020
  Apple   15/02/2020
  Apple   10/02/2020

runcell(2, 'C:/Users/Paddy3118/Google Drive/Code/fruit_orderings.py')

AN ORDERING OF ITEMS:
  Banana  16/04/2020
  Apple   15/04/2020
  Orange  15/03/2020
  Banana  21/03/2020
  Apple   10/04/2020
  Orange  13/03/2020
  Apple   15/03/2020
  Banana  16/03/2020
  Apple   10/03/2020
  Apple   15/02/2020
  Apple   10/02/2020

runcell(2, 'C:/Users/Paddy3118/Google Drive/Code/fruit_orderings.py')

AN ORDERING OF ITEMS:
  Banana  16/04/2020
  Apple   15/04/2020
  Orange  15/03/2020
  Apple   10/04/2020
  Orange  13/03/2020
  Banana  21/03/2020
  Banana  16/03/2020
  Apple   15/03/2020
  Apple   10/03/2020
  Apple   15/02/2020
  Apple   10/02/2020

runcell(2, 'C:/Users/Paddy3118/Google Drive/Code/fruit_orderings.py')

AN ORDERING OF ITEMS:
  Banana  16/04/2020
  Apple   15/04/2020
  Orange  15/03/2020
  Orange  13/03/2020
  Apple   10/04/2020
  Banana  21/03/2020
  Apple   15/03/2020
  Banana  16/03/2020
  Apple   10/03/2020
  Apple   15/02/2020
  Apple   10/02/2020
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not completely sure I understand the entire question, but I think I get "most recent items but without identical items appearing next to each other," so I'm going to focus on that part.

If you can separate the identical items while preserving ordering between them, it's pretty easy; first do the sort on date, and then do the separation.  I wasn't able to think of an existing function that does that separation, so I hacked one together that works "well enough" to produce reasonable output:

```
from datetime import datetime
from typing import Any, Callable, List, Optional, TypeVar

_I = TypeVar('_I')


def declump(
    items: List[_I], 
    key: Optional[Callable[[_I], Any]] = None
) -> None:
    """
    Separate identical items by doing repeated swaps of the form:
    AAB -> ABA  (in-place)
    Existing ordering is preserved within sets of identical items,
    but not between non-identical items.
    fixme: we can end up with a clump at the very end of the list!
    Easy workaround is to reverse the list and declump again.
    """
    if key is None:
        key = lambda x: x
    i = 0
    key(items[i])
    while i < len(items) - 2:
        if (
            key(items[i]) == key(items[i+1])
            and key(items[i+1]) != key(items[i+2])
        ):
            items[i+1], items[i+2] = items[i+2], items[i+1]
            if i > 0:
                i -= 1
                continue
        i += 1


produce = [
    ('Apple', '10/02/2020'),
    ('Apple', '15/02/2020'),
    ('Apple', '10/03/2020'),
    ('Apple', '15/03/2020'),
    ('Apple', '10/04/2020'),
    ('Apple', '15/04/2020'),
    ('Banana', '16/03/2020'),
    ('Banana', '21/03/2020'),
    ('Banana', '16/04/2020'),
    ('Orange', '13/03/2020'),
    ('Orange', '15/03/2020'),
]


produce.sort(key=lambda t: datetime.strptime(t[1], r'%d/%m/%Y'), reverse=True)
produce.reverse()
declump(produce, key=lambda t: t[0])
produce.reverse()
declump(produce, key=lambda t: t[0])
print('\n'.join(t[0].ljust(8) + t[1] for t in produce))
```

produces:

```
Apple   15/04/2020
Banana  16/04/2020
Apple   10/04/2020
Banana  21/03/2020
Apple   15/03/2020
Banana  16/03/2020
Apple   10/03/2020
Orange  15/03/2020
Apple   15/02/2020
Orange  13/03/2020
Apple   10/02/2020
```

I'm almost positive there's a better way to write that `declump` function but the kludge of flipping it over and calling it again seems to compensate for its deficiencies so I'll leave improvements as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: The problem with that the first time we see Orange is all the way down on the 8th item so if we have our data split/shown in groups of 3 for example then our first 3 groups will all have two Apples on show.

The importance of not showing same items next to eachother gets less and less important the further down the "groups" we go so it's mostly okay having 4 apples right at the end of the list.